# django class page view not rendering template code

Tags: django, templates, django-forms, django-views

I wanted to use class based views and went through the django documentation and I get noerror messages but wind up with an empty template.  I had it working with the non-classed based views.  How do I reformat the code so that it renders the template?  The template consists of a title, some headings, a navigational menu, flags for selecting instructions in different languages,
followed by a form which shows a flag, policy name char field, and a check box control.  I think the initial `= {'key': 'value'}` in the view forms incorrect but I don't know what to replace it with.  Thanks in advance.

```
forms.py

from django import forms 
from policytracker.models import Flag, Label_Links

class PolicyStartForm( forms.Form ):
    flags = Flag.objects.all()
    policy   = Label_Links.objects.all().filter(iso_language='en')[0]

    frm_policy1_name=[]

    for flag in flags:
        frm_policy1_name.append(forms.CharField(max_length=40))       

    policy_dict = { 'new_policy_link' :policy.nav_section_new_policy_link,
                   'new_policy_label' :policy.nav_section_new_policy_label,
                    'graphs_link':policy.nav_section_graphs_link,
                 'graphs_label'  :policy.nav_section_graphs_label,
                 'account_link'  :policy.nav_section_account_link,
                 'account_label' :policy.nav_section_account_label,
                 'policy_list_link':policy.nav_section_list_policies_link,
               'policy_list_label':policy.nav_section_list_policies_label, 
               'login_link'       :policy.nav_section_login_link,
                 'login_label'    :policy.nav_section_login_label,
               'new_policy1_heading' :policy.new_policy1_heading,
                 'new_policy1_title_label':policy.new_policy1_title_label,
    'policy_needs_translation_label':policy.new_policy1_needs_trans_label,
           'policy1_submit_label': policy.new_policy1_submit_button_label,
               'policy1_tip_msg' :policy.new_policy1_tip_msg,
                 't_logged_in'        :True,
                 'frm_policy_name'    :frm_policy1_name,
                 't_flags'            :flags }
</code>


<code>
views.py

# coding=utf-8
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from policytracker.forms import LoginForm, PolicyStartForm
from policytracker.models import Flag, Label_Links
from django.views import View

class PolicyStartView(View):
    template_name = 'policystart.html'
    initial = {'key': 'value'}
    form_class = PolicyStartForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
</code>

<code>
policystart.html

{% extends "policy-base.html" %}

{% block navsection %}  
<div class="container top">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <h1 class="text-center">{{ new_policy1_heading }}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% if t_policy_details %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <h4 class="text-nowrap text-left" id="week_start">2017-02-11</h4></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
            <h4 class="text-center" id="week_number">Week 1</h4></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <h4 class="text-nowrap text-right" id="week_end">2016-09-18</h4></div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand hidden navbar-link" href="#"> Policies</a>
                        <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li class="hidden" role="presentation"><a href="{{ new_policy_link }}">{{ new_policy_label }}</a></li>
                            <li {% if not t_logged_in %} class="hidden" {% endif %} role="presentation"><a href="{{ graphs_link }}">{{ graphs_label }}</a></li>
                            <li {% if not t_logged_in %} class="hidden" {% endif %} role="presentation"><a href="{{ account_link }}">{{ account_label }}</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="{{ policy_list_link }}">{{ policy_list_label }}</a></li>
                            {% if not t_logged_in %} <li role="presentation"><a href="{{ login_link }}">{{ login_label }}</a></li> {% endif %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% include "pol-new1-lang.html" %}    
</div>

<div class="container middle-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-3">
            <p> </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
            <h4>{{ new_policy1_title_label }}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
            <h4 class="text-center">{{ policy_needs_translation_label }}</h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% load static %}

        {% for f in t_flags %}
        <div class="row flag">
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-2"><img src="{% static f.flag_image_filename %}"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-9">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="policytitle">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="needstranslation">
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}

        <div class="row enter">
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-3">
                <p> </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-8">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">{{ policy1_submit_label }}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <div class="row enter">
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-3">
             <p> </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-8">
             <p>{{ policy1_tip_msg }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

</code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a load of variables in your template, but you aren't actually sending any of them to the context; the only thing your view passes is `form`. If you want to use things like `new_policy1_heading`, `policy_needs_translation_label` and `t_flags` you need to define them in your view and send them to the template from there.

Actually, it looks like you've completely misunderstood the jobs of forms and views. All the code you've currently put inside your form actually belongs in the view, and you should use `policy_dict` as the template context. It doesn't look like you need a form class at all.

Even there, though, you're doing much more work than you need to. There's no need to send all the specific fields of the policy object individually; just send `policy` and then in the template you can do `{{ policy.policy_needs_translation_label }}` etc.